# Google Pie charts legend navigation icons color

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, legend, pie-chart, legend-properties

How do we change the color for the navigation links in google pie charts.(the blue text in bottom right corner)[image: the blue text in bottom right corner]

Comment: can you share the code or create a jsfiddle, i did not find multiple google charts with links

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change it like this:

```
legend: {
         position: 'right',
         textStyle: {fontSize: 12,bold: false,fontName:'MyriadPro-Regular'},
         pagingTextStyle: {color: '#666'},
         scrollArrows:{
             activeColor: '#666',
             inactiveColor:'#cccccc'}
     }
```